# Parentheses in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I am evaluating a very simple piece of code in Ocaml toplevel:

```
let p5 () = print_int 5;;
p5 ();;

print_string "*************************";;

let p4 = print_int 4;;
p4;;
```

And it returns:

```
val p5 : unit -> unit = <fun>
#   5- : unit = ()
#   *************************- : unit = ()
#   4val p4 : unit = ()
#   - : unit = ()
```

My questions are

1. What does `()` mean in `let p5 () = print_int 5;;`?
2. What do `-` and `()` mean in `#   5- : unit = ()`?
3. Is `p4` a function?
4. Why is there a `4` in the beginning of `#   4val p4 : unit = ()`?
5. It seems that `()` could be used in Ocaml code to hide side effect, could anyone show me an example?

Comment: you might want to get used to using `print_endline` instead of `print_string` because it automatically prints an endline after

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here some answers:

1. `()` is the unit type value. The unit type is a type with only one value. This is usually used to produce functions which either return nothing meaningful or take nothing meaningful. Remember, that in OCaml all functions alway have to return something and take some arguments, so the unit type is used to get around this limitation. Think of this similar to the `void` type in C, C++ or Java.
2. There are two lines interleaved. The `5` is printed by the `print_int` function and not by the toplevel. The toplevel just returns `- : unit = ()` without the `5`. The toplevel is telling you that it did not create any new bindings `-` and that the last returned value is of type `unit` and has the value `()`.
3. No. It does not take any arguments, so it is not a function.
4. Again there are two lines interleaved. The `4` is printed by the `print_int` function. At this time, the toplevel is telling you, that it created a new binding `p4`, that this variable carries a value of type `unit` and that the stored value is `()`.
5. No, `()` is not used to hide side effects. It is usually used to create functions, which have side effects, and thus need not take any kind of argument.

Answer (score 6):

LiKao has explained all the key points already, but I thought it might make more sense if you entered your definitions one line at a time, which would show which responses come from which inputs.  Lines entered by the person start with `#`.

```
# let p5 () = print_int 5;;
val p5 : unit -> unit = <fun>
```

This defines p5 as a function that accepts values of type `unit` and returns values of type `unit`.  There's only one value of type unit, which is written as `()`.  So these are exactly the parentheses you are asking about (I think).  Note that the `()` appearing in your definition is a pattern for the values accepted by the function.  As a pattern, `()` matches itself (like all constants used as patterns).

```
# p5 ();;
5- : unit = ()
```

This is a little confusing.  The `5` is written by your function `p5`.  The rest is the response from the OCaml top-level.  It's saying that the result of your expression is of type `unit` and has the value `()`.  It makes sense, `print_int` is of type `int -> unit`.

```
# print_string "*************************";;
*************************- : unit = ()
```

There's a similar confusion here.  The asterisks `*` are written by `print_string`.  The rest shows the result, which again is of type `unit` with value `()`.

```
# let p4 = print_int 4;;
4val p4 : unit = ()
```

Same thing here.  The `4` is written by `print_int`.  The rest shows that the top level has defined a symbol named `p4` whose type is `unit` and whose value is `()`.  Again, this makes sense because `print_int` returns `unit` type and `()` is the only value of that type.  You can tell from the type of `p4` that it is *not* a function.  Functions have an arrow (`->`) in the type.  `p4` is just a value of type `unit`.

```
# p4;;
- : unit = ()
```

Here you ask the top-level for the type and value of `p4`, and it tells you (again) that `p4` is of type `unit` and has the value `()`.

Answer (score 2):

Your last question is how `()` is used to "hide a side-effect". You are probably referring to the delayed evaluation of a function. Here is an example:

```
 let p x = print_string "abc";;
 let q = print_string "abc";;
```

There is a crucial difference between `p` and `q`. The difference is that `p` is a function of type `'a -> unit` while `q` is a value of type `unit`. When you define `p`, nothing is printed. The string "abc" will be printed only when you apply the function `p` to an argument, i.e. when you evaluate `p 1` or `p "blah"` or whatever. (The function `p` takes arguments of any type and ignores them.) So in the case of `p`, you have "hidden a side-effect" inside the function.

It is pointless to have an argument, "x", in the definition of "p x", since "x" is not used at all. So for simplicity the type "unit" is used, so that the definition of "p" looks like "let p () = ...". This is the same as

```
 let p = fun () -> print_string "abc";;
```

The function "p" is then used as "p ()". This may be confusing if you first learned programming languages like C, Java, etc., where () are used for arguments of all functions. But in OCAML, `()` is a special symbol that denotes an "empty value", and this value has a special type called "unit".

A totally different thing happens as you define `q`: the string "abc" is printed right away, since this is the side-effect of evaluating "print_string", and `q` becomes equal to `()`, since `()` is the resulting value obtained by evaluating "print_string".

Answer (score 0):

I am late to the party, but I want to point out that using `()` in

```
let p5 () = print_int 5
```

Has a pattern matching in the argument of `p5`. It is equivalent of this:

```
let p5 x = match x with () -> print_int 5
```

Or this:

```
let p5 = function () -> print_int 5
```

Or even this:

```
let p5 = fun x -> match x with () -> print_int 5
```

This distinction is important in the following code:

```
let f (x, y) = print_int (x + y)
let g x y = print_int (x + y)
```

`f` receives only one parameter (the pair `(x, y)`), while `g` receives two parameters. `f` thus has the type `(int * int) -> unit` and `g` has the type `int -> int -> unit`. So `f` could be written like this:

```
let f pair = match pair with (x, y) -> print_int (x + y)
```